# Does anyone have experience of load balancing an apt repository? Can it be done?

Tags: load-balancing, apt

I'd just like a bit of a head start on this if anyone's any experience of it. Searching for things like "apt load balanced" gives remarkably little of use.

We currently have an apt repository on a multi-purpose server, want to split off apache to a load balanced two machine setup, and I'm just wondering if the apt repository can go with it without too much fanfare? I'm thinking along the lines of apt-key issues, file replication ...

I'm not necessarily asking for a detailed how-to (that would be nice, though ;-)), just some re-assurance there are no blockers surrounding it.

Answer (score 0):

An apt repo is just a bunch of static files served over https (or http, but please don't do that anymore). This is about the simplest possible configuration for a web site.

The only thing I would suggest is to synchronize the `pool` directory (which contains the dpkg packages) before the `dists` directory (which contains the metadata), so that the repos remain in a consistent state and the files the metadata point to are always available.